# Calling Javascript based on PHP conditional when libraries load in the footer

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have the following in the body of a php page:

```
<?php if($foo) : ?>

    <script>
        js_func();
    </script>

<?php else: ?>

    //Do Something else

<?php endif; ?>
```

Based on the PHP conditional I either do or do not want to run js_func().

However if I am loading all of my scripts (including the script the defines js_func()) at the bottom of my page this will results in an error.

One possible solution would be to load the external script BEFORE calling js_func() but I understand that for performance reasons I shouldn't do that.

I could use $(document).ready(function() {}); but this just moves the error as jQuery is also loaded in the footer.

The only other options I can think of is to use window.onload or never call a js function inline. How does everyone else solve this issue?

Many thanks.

EDIT:

@Nile - Im not sure what you mean. Why would I comment out code that I want to execute? 
@haynar1658 - I don't want to execute JS in the else scenario. 
@Matthew Blancarte - Understood. That leads to my question, what's the best way to make sure that the js I need loads before that function is instantiated? Include the script before it? Use window.onload? etc.

Comment: irrelevant, but why don't you conditionally add `//` (comments) before the js statement instead of removing it completely?

Comment: seems that you've forgotten to add `<script>` tag in the `ELSE` statement, maybe that is the problem? if in both cases you will output JS, than move the `<script>` tag to the top level

Comment: OP... You absolutely need to load the script that defines js_func() prior to instantiating that function.

Comment: It is a good idea to load js at the bottom of the page, but it would not degrade performance to move your PHP code to below that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are making a rod for your own back. Depend on the question you described, you want to **put all the function definition script block after the place where them being called. It's Impossible!**
If you indeed need to do this, does this can help? :

```
<script>    
    var fns = []; /* use fns to keep all the js code  
                     which call the functions defined after. */  
</script>


<script>
    //wrapp your code in a function and then push it into fns.   
    fns.push(function(){  
        js_func();  
    }) 
</script>


//script tags for loading your function  definition js script.  
<script src="path/to/jquery-any-version.js"></script>  
<script src="path/to/other-libraries.js"></script>


<script>
    //after your definition js scripts are loaded ,  call all functions in fns  
    for(var i=0, len=fns.length; i<len; i++){  
        var fn = fns[i];  
        fn.apply(this, []/* arguments that provided  as an array */);  
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Klvoek. I think 'you are making a rod for your own back' is the most important part of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the script to the top.

The difference (if there is one) is very small.
The believe that putting the `<script>s` in the `<head>` slows down the page is not "accepted" by all developers.

Comment: I didn't think it was something you could 'reject' - loading external js files blocks loading other assets. Or so I thought. Care to elaborate or cite sources for that opinion?

Comment: @adampetrie. jQuery minified version weight is **32KB**. Now do you think it will have any effect on the users???

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to echo it in PHP?

```
<?php if($foo) {
echo "<script> js_func(); </script>";
}else{
echo "something else";
}
```

Comment: Echoing with PHP will make no difference because the PHP will have executed before the browser renders the content. You've offered a different way to create the exact same problem.