# Load different PHP files based on JavaScript availability

Tags: javascript, php, html, require

I currently have the code below (PHP)

```
<?php
    require_once __DIR__.'/includes/Connect.php';
    require_once __DIR__.'/includes/Nojs.php';
    require_once __DIR__.'/includes/Main.php';
    require_once __DIR__.'/includes/footer.php';
?>
```

I want `Main.php` to load only if JavaScript is enabled, and `Nojs.php` to load only is JavaScript is disabled.

Surrounding `Nojs.php` with  tags does nothing (See below code)

```
<?php
    require_once __DIR__.'/includes/Connect.php';
?>
<noscript>
    <?php
        require_once __DIR__.'/includes/Nojs.php';
    ?>
</noscript>
<?php
    require_once __DIR__.'/includes/Main.php';
    require_once __DIR__.'/includes/footer.php';
?>
```

Since I know the PHP cannot access the browser as it is done server-side, is it possible to try to use HTML (Like I attempted) or other JavaScript to get it to work?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Creating a new file for `nojs.php` and using meta refresh works, but there is a noticeable delay. The page starts loading the original URL and then redirects to the other. A visitor can quite easily cancel the page load process and stop the page load before the redirect. They will have a partly loaded page, but all the content they really need will be there. Is there a way to force an immediate redirect (Yes, "content" is set to "0" per the below anwser)?

Comment: Does this address your situation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361321/calling-javascript-based-on-php-conditional-when-libraries-load-in-the-footer

Comment: As you say "PHP cannot access the browser as it is done server-side" — the `<noscript>` tag is processed by the browser after the PHP has finished its server-side execution. It _may_ be possible to put the `<noscript>` tag in the `Nojs.php` file itself, and always require_once that file... kind of depends on what's in the Nojs.php file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another PHP file with no js version when first PHP loaded it will check if no js support will redirect to no js version of PHP

```html
<noscript>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=nojs-version.php">
</noscript>
```

Edit: It is also mentioned by W3C as technique without confusing user
https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H76.html

Comment: I thought that using meta-refresh is considered bad practice and should never be used. Am I wrong?

Comment: I don’t think so, please elaborate, for what reason?

Comment: Let’s talk with official data https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H76.html It clearly states `The objective of this technique is to enable redirects on the client side without confusing the user.`

Comment: what do you mean? noscript tag is for checking wether browser support js or not. Im just going to let the data talks here again https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript

Comment: Although "content" is set to 0, it takes some time (like 2 seconds) to redirect. In that time, the visitor can just cancel the page load and nothing is affected.